# Will I loose manufacturer updates if I root my phone

Tags: rooting, updates

I have ASUS Zenfone 2 Laser with Marshmallow but I want to root my phone fot certain reasons but don't want to loose OTA updates from manufacturer. Please let me know if any work around is possible.

Comment: No you will not lose the updates.
But to be sure, just use one of the apps to create a backup of your device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most phones, especially the newer ones, you cannot receive OTA updates, since `/system` is modified by rooting and it fails the verification for OTA updates.
To better understand details about verification see answers to this question  [What specifically prevents OTAs from being taken on modified /systems, and why can't it be shut off?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131851/131553)

*Systemless Root* is an option to prevent this. In this method of rooting only the `boot` partition is modified, keeping `/system` intact. Prior to flashing OTA one needs to flash stock boot and recovery images to allow OTA updates . You can read more about systemless root in the answers here [Systemless Root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132753/131553)

Do ensure you research the linked XDA thread in answers and choose the right version for your device, based on user feedback